# Single log generation for single click and double click c++

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, mouseevent

I have an application to log mouse clicks. I need a single log for each clicks. During double click,  the mouse button generates a sequence of messages: WM_LBUTTONDOWN, WM_LBUTTONUP, WM_LBUTTONDBCLK and WM_LBUTTONUP. So I am getting 4 logs for each double click. Since logs are handled with generating messages.

Is there any way to restrict the other logs and get the log of WM_LBUTTONDBCLK only.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you know, the Windows can't detect "double click" from first pressing. So, you should do this himself.
For example, at first single click you start timer (for example, upto 500 ms). In case the timer is over and double click hasn't been received you log single click. In other case you should log double click.

Comment: Not 500ms, but rather the return value of [GetDoubleClickTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getdoubleclicktime).